# Unir colunas no python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Olá. Eu tenho esse arquivo ([arquivo](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ak2pOptPmINYozaT9QYjjaZG7nqd)) onde preciso unir as colunas yyyy, mm, dd, hour (ano, mês, dia e hora) em uma única coluna, e ficasse nesse formato 20180101010000, conclusão: ano+ mês (com dois digitos)+dia (com dois digitos)+ hora (com mais 00 no fim), 2018 + 01+ 01+ 010000.

Mas tudo que consegui foi 2018.01.01.01. Precisava tirar esses pontos e corrigir algumas coisas. O código até o momento:

```
arq_csv = pd.read_csv('arquivo.csv')
csv_date_list = []
for index, rows in arq_csv.iterrows():
    csv_date_list.append(str(rows[' yyyy'])+str(rows[' mm'])+str(rows[' dd'])+str(int(rows[' hour'])))
print(csv_date_list)
```

P.S.: O doc, quando for colocar a coluna entre aspas, e.g. ' yyyy', tem que colocar um espaço antes do nome, senão não vai ser lida a coluna.

Obrigada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Melhor do que simplesmente concatenar os dados das colunas numa lista de Python, em que você teria os timestamps,mas como objetos de texto, não como datas, e dissociados dos dados originais é fazer esse tipo de processamento fazendo uso dos métodos do próprio Pandas.

Nesse caso, o mais indicado é usar o método `apply` - ele pode chamar uma função em linha por linha do seu dataframe, e agregar os valores retornados para cada linha em uma Série . Essa série vai compartilhar o Index com seu dataframe original, e pode ser concatenada como uma coluna extra. (E aí, você pode eliminar as colunas com elementos avulsos da data).

E, enquanto estamos nisso, o dataframe, ao contrário de um arquivo "csv" onde "tudo é texto" pode conter objetos mais elaborados - como datetimes, que contém um dado de "timestamp" com data, horas, minutos - que pode ser ordenado, levar em conta horário de verão e fuso-horário, subtraído de outros valores de data-e-hora para se encontrar duração, e assim por diante.

Se a função a ser aplicada retornar um objeto datetime, o pandas automaticamente cria uma série com esse conteúdo:

```
from datetime import datetime
def processa(linha):
   # transformar as colunas desejadas em uma lista de valores inteiros:
   valores = [int(val) for val in (linha[" yyyy"], linha[" mm"], linha[" dd"], linha[" hour"], linha[" min"]
   # criar objeto datetime:
   # O construtor do python "datetime" recebe na ordem os valores 
   # para ano, mes, dia, horas e minutos - o operador "*"
   # desempacota esses argumentos, que estão em uma lista, na chamada:
   return datetime(*valores)

# Ler o seu dataframe:
df = pd.read_csv("B116353.csv")
# criar a série com as datas e horas:
timestamps = df.apply(processa, axis=1)
timstamps.name = "timestamps" 

# Criar um novo dataframe com as colunas de interesse - 
# descobrir indice da coluna apos " min":
remainder_start = list(df.columns).index(" min")

new_df = pd.concat(
    (df[["id_argos", " id_wmo"]],
     timestamps,
     df[list(df.columns)[remainder_start + 1: ]
    ),
    axis=1
)
```

Pronto - agora você tem a coluna "timestamp" com um objeto datetime combinando os números de 5 colunas - e pode prosseguir com o processamento do seu dataframe.

A penultima linha da chamada ao "concat" usa  Python "puro" (isso é, sem pandas) - para selecionar os nomes de todas as colunas pra frente de " min" sem que eles precisem ser digitados -  esse nomes são passados como uma lista de strings como um índice para o dataframe, e isso seleciona aquelas colunas. A chamada ao "concat" então usa as duas primeiras colunas do frame original, a serie de tempo que criamos, e todas as colunas restantes para criar um novo dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

Boa tarde Helena, 
Você pode realizar a formatação da string no formato que você quiser utilizando o `str.format()` que no caso é um método já contido no tipo string. No caso você pode utilizar da seguinte maneira:

```
csv_date_list.append("{}{}{}{}".format(rows[' yyyy'],rows[' mm'],rows[' dd'],rows[' hour']))
```

Desta forma você pode definir o formato que lhe for mais conveniente.

Referência

- https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: isso cria a lista, mas não ajuda a incorporar as datas criadas no dataframe para continuidade da análise.
O método format apesar de funcionar é bem pouco prático -a partir do Python 3.6 é muito mais conveniente usar as `f-strings` para esse tipo de expressão.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui aqui.

```
csv_date_list.append(str(int(rows[" yyyy"]))+str(int(rows[' mm'])).zfill(2)+str(int(rows[' dd'])).zfill(2)+str(int(rows[' hour']))+'0000')
```